# What do "source" and "dataScope" mean in admin form Ui component configuraion file

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent

There are **source** and **dataScope** nodes in Magento2 admin form UI component configuration. What do they mean and how are they supposed to be used?

```
<field name="title">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Page Title</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">title</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Answer (score 32):

#### Regarding the `source` node

The `source` node's value corresponds to a key in the data array returned by the `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProviderInterface::getData` method of your UI component.

---

For example, let's consider the **customer_form** UI.
File [`/Magento/Customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml)

From here you can see that for most of the fields Magento uses the `customer` value under the [`source`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml#L189) node.
But wait, for the fields under the `address` fieldset this value has changed to the [`address`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml#L341).

Now let's take a brief look at the corresponding **DataProvider** for the **customer_form** UI component.
The class is `\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\DataProvider`.

Roughly, the method [`getData`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/Customer/DataProvider.php#L224-L245) of this class is responsible for returning data that is populated to the corresponding fields declared by the **customer_form** component.
As you can guess now, the **customer** value of the `source` node tells us to use the value stored under the key **customer** in the `getData` method, while the **address** `source` points to the data stored under the key **address** in the returned data.

Closer look:

`<field name="firstname" formElement="input">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>`

The field above takes its firstname value from the data stored under the key **customer** returned by the customer's **DataProvider**.

While in the case below, the source of the firstname value is the data stored under the key **address**:

`<field name="firstname" formElement="input">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>`

---

#### Regarding the `dataScope` node

The `dataScope` node allows you to change a value for the **name** attribute of your input (field), e.g.,

`<field name="title">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">field_name</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>`

The result input will be rendered as follows: `<input name="field_name"...>`

You can also write the values into the `dataScope` node separated by dots: `customer.address.firstname`, in this case the result input rendered as follows: `<input name="customer[address][firstname]"...>`
Here is where the magic [happens](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/abstract.js#L121-L132).

Also the `dataScope` node [changes the path of the retrieved value](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/abstract.js#L60-L62) for a field. This is achieved by means of the [linking](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_linking_concept.html) technique.

Comment: omg all I want is a datepicker LOL, gotta love Magento 

Comment: wonderfull artical bro

Answer (score 2):

this is mean what your field will be sent in POST like your "dataScope" value, in your situation for example post request will be like `['title'] => var`

Comment: You missed one question. What's the meaning of **source**? If it is datasource, why the argument is **page**, not **page_listing_data_source**?