# Admin form not pulling through form values when turning collapsible to tabbed form using ui form xml

Tags: admin, uicomponent, adminform, ui

I'm working on an admin ui form

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Announce/blob/hotfix/tabs/view/adminhtml/ui_component/xigen_announce_group_form.xml

I've added tabs

In order to get the tabs working I've removed the `<item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>` from the XML

My form elements have changed from `<input name="name">` to `<input name="general[name]">`

Which makes sense

However when editing a record the form fields now appear blank. I've forgotten a step.

It's to do with dataScope and chaining

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked this comment

`The source node's value corresponds to a key in the data array returned by the \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProviderInterface::getData method of your UI component.`

From https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/219692/70343

Sure enough

```php
    /**
     * Get data
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $model) {
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()]['general'] = $model->getData();  // key part
        }
        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('xigen_announce_group');

        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $model->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()]['general'] = $model->getData(); // key part
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('xigen_announce_group');
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
```

Helped to look at this https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/Customer/DataProvider.php#L214-L252

I hope this helps someone. Might save them an hour.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!! I am looking for a solution of this problem since 8 hours.